# Google Apps Script - Better way to do a Vlookup

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am doing a kind of VLOOKUP operation in a column with about 3K cells. I am using the following function to do it. I commented on what the code is doing in the function, but to summarize:

- It creates a map from values to search for from a table with metadata
- It iterates each value of a given range, and searches for coincidences in the previous map
- If coincidences are found, it uses the index to capture the second column of the metadata table
- Finally, sets the value captured in another cell

This is the code:

```
function questions_categories() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("data_processed");

  // get metadata. This will work as the table to look into
  // Column B contains the matching element
  // Column C contains the string to return
  var metadata = ss.getSheetByName("metadata").getRange('B2:C').getValues()

  // Just get the different values from the column B
  var dataList = metadata.map(x => x[0])

  // Used to define the last cell where to apply the vlookup
  var Avals = sheet.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
  var Alast = Avals.filter(String).length;

  // define the range to apply the "vlookup"
  const questions_range = sheet.getRange("Q2:Q" + Alast);
  
  forEachRangeCell(questions_range, (cell) => {
  
    var searchValue = cell.getValue();
    // is the value to search in the dataList we defined previously?
    var index = dataList.indexOf(searchValue);

    if (index === -1) {
      // if not, throw an error
      throw new Error('Value not found')
    } else {
      // if the value is there, use the index in which that appears to get the value of column C
      var foundValue = metadata[index][1]
      // set the value in two columns to the right
      cell.offset(0, 2).setValue(`${foundValue}`);
    }
  })
}
```

`forEachRangeCell()` is a helper function to iterate through the range.

This works very well, but it resolves 3-4 cells per second, which is not very efficient if I need to check thousands of data. I was wondering if there is a more performant way to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To improve performance, use `Range.setValues()` instead of `Range.setValue()`, like this:

```js
function questions_categories() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const source = { values: ss.getRange('metadata!B2:C').getValues() };
  const target = { range: ss.getRange('data_processed!Q2:Q') };
  source.keys = source.values.map(row => row[0]);
  target.keys = target.range.getValues().flat();
  const result = target.keys.map(key => [source.values[source.keys.indexOf(key)]?.[1]]);
  target.range.offset(0, 2).setValues(result);
}
```

See [Apps Script best practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations).